# Как сравнить подмассивы?

Tags: javascript

Как правильно сравнить данные массива. У меня есть массив с тремя подмассивами:

```
var arr = [
  [10, 10, 10, 20, 60],
  [10, 10, 50, 10, 10],
  [20, 10, 30, 20, 10]
];
```

Мне нужно собрать один массив, с максимальными значениями этих трех массивов. Длина под массивов всегда одинаковая, если в одном 5 значений то и в других двух столько же.

На выходе должен получится вот такой массив: `var arr = [20, 10, 50, 20, 60]`

Comment: Вы умеете писать циклы? А вложенные циклы проходили? Уточните в чем у вас проблема с решением вопроса.

Comment: и какой вывод должен быть для предоставленного примера?

Comment: На выходе должен получится вот такой массив: var arr = [20, 10, 50, 20, 60]

Comment: Добавь это в сам вопрос. Отредактировать вопрос можно с помощью кнопки [edit] под вопросом

Comment: `должен получится вот такой массив: var arr = [20, 10, 50, 20, 60] ` -
 как это вписывается в концепцию:  `Мне нужно собрать один массив, с максимальными значениями этих трех массивов.` ?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, ну так он действительно из максимальных элементов на соответствующих позициях :-)

Comment: @Grundy таки а причем тут 10 и 20 в результате?

Comment: @VovaBunchykov, количество подмассивов всегда 3 или может быть больше/меньше?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, ну так ты посмотри на второй элемент: во всех трех массивах это 10, вот она и вошла в результат

Comment: @Grundy а 20? должно же быть `[30,50,60]` - не?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, не, ты не понял :-) у тебя на выходе должен получиться массив той же длины что и подмассивы, в котором элемент - это максимальный элемент из подмассивов на соответствующем индексе

Comment: @Grundy понял, сравнение по столбцам, а не по массивам.

Comment: Сори если не правильно сформулировал вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const arr = [
  [10, 10, 10, 20, 60],
  [10, 10, 50, 10, 10],
  [20, 10, 30, 20, 10]
];

const arrLength = arr.length;
const subArrLength = arr[0].length;
const flattenArr = [].concat(...arr);
const result = [];

for (let i = 0; i < subArrLength; i++) {
  const indexes = [];
  
  for (let j = 0; j < arrLength; j++) {
    indexes.push(flattenArr[i + j * subArrLength]);
  }

  result.push(Math.max(...indexes));
}

console.log(result); // [20, 10, 50, 20, 60];
```

Comment: а зачем _flattenArr_ нужен? почему не использовать `arr[i][j]`?

Comment: Рекомендую использовать вариант @Grundy с `reduce`. Declarative > Imperative.

Answer (score 1):

Самое простое решение: бежать по одному из внутренних массивов и сравнивать текущий элемент со значениями на этом же индексе в соседних массивах и выбирать максимальный.

Реализовать можно с помощью [метода map](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), например так:

```js
function* nextMax(arr, index) { // получаем массив соответствующий колонке index
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    yield arr[i][index];
  }
}

var arr = [
  [10, 10, 10, 20, 60],
  [10, 10, 50, 10, 10],
  [20, 10, 30, 20, 10]
];

var dest = arr[0].map((cur, i) => Math.max(...(nextMax(arr, i))));

console.log(dest);
```

---

Альтернативным решение было бы использование [метода reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) с постепенным сравнением:

```js
var arr = [
  [10, 10, 10, 20, 60],
  [10, 10, 50, 10, 10],
  [20, 10, 30, 20, 10]
];

var dest = arr.reduce((acc, cur) =>
  acc.map((el, i) => Math.max(el, cur[i]))
)

console.log(dest);
```

Comment: На выходе массив с массивом.

Comment: @YozhEzhi, поправил